# Quickblox WebRTC issue: onCallListener is not working inside my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, quickblox

So, basically I'm trying to receive a call from provider to my app. For that purpose Quickblox gives us a listener to receive the upcoming calls `onCallListener`. So here is my code snippet that should work but doesn't.

```
const calleesIds = [4104]
const sessionType = QB.webrtc.CallType.VIDEO
const additionalOptions = {}
let callSession = QB.webrtc.createNewSession(calleesIds, sessionType, null, additionalOptions)
console.log(callSession, "SESSION")

const mediaParams = {
  audio: true,
  video: true,
  options: {
    muted: true,
    mirror: true,
  },
  elemId: "myVideoStream"
}

QB.webrtc.onCallListener = function(session: any, extension: object) {
  callSession = session
  console.log('asdasd')
  // if you are going to take a call
  session.getUserMedia(mediaParams, function (error: object, stream: object) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error)
    } else {
      session.accept(extension)
      session.attachMediaStream("videoStream", stream)
    }
  })
}
```

P.S. I also integrated chat which works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by myself! Whenever you create a user and dialog id, search that user in the quickblox dashboard by the dialogId and change its settings: you will see that userId and providerId is the same which is wrong. So put your userId in the userId field and save that. After that you video calling listeners will work fine!)
P. S. also in the backend replace provider token with user token.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).